# The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid

Tags: java, kotlin, maven, 2009scape

I did a fresh clone of the latest 2009scape development server, but when trying to run the server exec task I get the following error:

```
The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid
```

I can see the [CICD pipelines](https://gitlab.com/2009scape/2009scape/-/pipelines) are running without issue, so it's not an issue with the pom.xml.